# Given a joint PDF verify that it is a joint density function

Tags: statistics

The function from `f(x,y)` is represented below where `0 < x < 1` and `0 < y < 2` 
$\int_0^2  \int_0^1 \frac{6}{7} (x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dxdy $

Upon solving that integral you get 1.

What can I conclude about this value, Does this mean the function is valid? what would be an example of a non valid outcome?

Comment: Anything other than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

A joint density function will have an always positive measure over the joint support, and the (double) integral over the joint support will equal 1.

The function $(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})$ is always positive over $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,2]$.

So perform the integration.   If the result is equal to $1$, you have a probability mass function over that support.   Otherwise you do not.

---

The reason this integral should be $1$ is that it hopefully represents the probability measure of the probability space.   That should be almost certain.